# How can I grab id of an HTML Element generated from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a Js file where I have generated simple Html code:

```
var id  = document.getElementById("Id1");
var html = "<div id = 'id2'>This is the text generated from JS</div>";

id.innerHTML = html;
```

The id "id1" exists in the HTML file. 
Now when I try to grab id2 in another function in returns null.

```
var result = document.getElementById("id2");
```

The value of variable "result" is showing null.

Comment: Where is `id2` in the code above? also you have capital V for `var`

Comment: I'm having no problems with it whatsoever [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/3xvhvqsv/). decapitalize the `Var` keywords and you should be okay.

Comment: The variable html is contained in div with id2, sorry I forgot to use the code tag

Answer (score 0):

As @Karl-Henry Martinsson mentioned before me the id is case sensitive. Please make sure you are typing in the correct id names, otherwise your code is correct. Here's a sample code that works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button get the HTML content of the div element with id1.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id='id1'>This is going to change</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = "<div id=\"id2\">This is the text generated from JS</div>";
    var y = document.getElementById("id1");
    y.innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```